# Authorizing AWS API Gateway requests from token in query string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have API Gateway set up with a Cognito authorizer that correctly authorizes any request with the id token in the header.

This is fine when requests are XHR based as I can add the header when preparing the request. However I can't add this when using `<audio src="http://api-gateway/...">` which is made directly by the browser.

The best I can do is append the token in the querystring (`?token=...`) but Cognito only accepts tokens in the headers.

Is there any way to get Cognito to authorize requests when they come from HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately API Gateway does not support security tokens in query string or path parameters. I do not see this changing in the short term so would recommend replacing any hardcoded HTML elements with appropriate JS client code.

Comment: Is this answer still valid in 2023? I'd also like to be able to pass the token in the query string parameters without using the lambda authorizer workarround just for this. Any other workarrounds besides the lambda?