# Signing AWS Api Gateway request in Unity3D C#

Tags: unity-game-engine, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm using Unity3D v5.5.1, with AWS-SDK-Unity v3.3.37.0.
Since the Api Gateway doesn't generate an SDK for C#/Unity3D I'm trying to sign (SigV4) the request my self and have encountered difficulties.

I've tried both [manually signing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html) and using the [AWS4Signer.cs](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-unity/blob/943b00bef0f0bd0b072148a939556ec24c973530/Assets/AWSSDK/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Internal/Auth/AWS4Signer.cs) class.

The Api Gateway method has the *Invoke with caller credentials*, and just returns a Hello World as a response.

Within unity I have a facebook login button which returns the FB credentials and tokens. Using Cognito Federated Identity's **GetCredentialsAsync** method I get an **ImmutableCredentials** object with the **Key, Secret and a Token**.

To access the api gateway url I'm using the AWS4Signer class here to construct a signed request. In the example below I've tried both adding the security token to the url parameters and without, also signing it and not signing with the token. All options don't work (As stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011489/authorizing-aws-api-gateway-requests-from-token-in-query-string))

This results in either the following responses:
1. The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

2. The security token included in the request is invalid.

How can I correctly sign the request from Unity3D?

Thanks in advance

**TestGet method:**

```
IEnumerator TestGet (ImmutableCredentials response)
        {
            ApiGatewayConfig clientConfig = new ApiGatewayConfig(); // a class I created wrapping the ClientConfig.cs
            var metrics = new RequestMetrics();

            var awsAccessKeyId = response.AccessKey;
            var awsSecretAccessKey = response.SecretKey;
            var awsToken = response.Token;

            AmazonWebServiceRequest req = new MyRequest(); // a clas I created wrapping the AmazonWebServiceRequest.cs class

            var url = "https://<url_to_api>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/securehello";

            IRequest request = new DefaultRequest(req,"execute-api");
            request.UseQueryString = true;

            request.HttpMethod = "GET";
            request.Endpoint = new System.Uri (url);
            request.ResourcePath = url;
            request.ContentStream = new MemoryStream();
            request.Parameters.Add("X-Amz-Expires",AWS4PreSignedUrlSigner.MaxAWS4PreSignedUrlExpiry.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

            request.AuthenticationRegion = "us-east-1";
            request.AlternateEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
            request.UseSigV4 = true;
            request.Headers.Add("X-Amz-Security-Token",awsToken);
            request.Parameters.Add("X-Amz-Security-Token",awsToken);


            AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
            Debug.Log ("a");
            signer.Sign(request,clientConfig,metrics,awsAccessKeyId,awsSecretAccessKey);
            var signerRes = signer.SignRequest(request,clientConfig,metrics,awsAccessKeyId,awsSecretAccessKey);
            Debug.Log ("b");
            var myParams =  string.Format("{0}&X-Amz-Security-Token={1}",signerRes.ForQueryParameters,awsToken);
            var dict = myParams.Split('&').Select(p=> p.Split('=')).GroupBy(p => p[0]).Select(p => p.First()).ToDictionary(p => p[0], p=>System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(p[1]));
            var myEncodedParams = string.Empty;
            bool isFirst = true;
            foreach (var key in dict.Keys) {
                myEncodedParams += string.Format("{0}{1}={2}",isFirst ? "" : "&",key,WWW.EscapeURL(dict[key]));
                isFirst = false;
            }

            var finalUrl = string.Format ("{0}?{1}", request.Endpoint.AbsoluteUri,myEncodedParams);

            UnityWebRequest uwr = new UnityWebRequest (finalUrl, "GET", new DownloadHandlerBuffer (), null);
            Debug.Log ( string.Format("\n\n\n{0}\n\n\n",finalUrl));
            Debug.Log ("Starting WebRequest");

            yield return uwr.Send();
            if (uwr.isError) {
                Debug.LogError (uwr.error);
            } else {
                Debug.Log (uwr.downloadHandler.text);   
            }
```

**Helper classes:**

```
public class ApiGatewayConfig : ClientConfig
    {
        private static readonly string UserAgentString =
            InternalSDKUtils.BuildUserAgentString("3.3.37.0");

        private string _userAgent = UserAgentString;


        public ApiGatewayConfig ()
        {
            this.AuthenticationServiceName = "execute-api";
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// The constant used to lookup in the region hash the endpoint.
        /// </summary>
        public override string RegionEndpointServiceName
        {
            get
            {
                return "execute-api";
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the ServiceVersion property.
        /// </summary>
        public override string ServiceVersion
        {
            get
            {
                return "2015-07-09";
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the value of UserAgent property.
        /// </summary>
        public override string UserAgent
        {
            get
            {
                return _userAgent;
            }
        }

    }

    public class MyRequest : AmazonWebServiceRequest
    {
        public MyRequest () {}
    }
```

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala, link doesn't work

Comment: thanks for trying to help me. i fixed it with code from this github repo: https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved.**

I've created some **examples** showing how to do this. Still work in progress, example shows how to sign a POST request from Unity 3D to Api Gateway endpoint that has "Invoke with caller credentials" (AWS_IAM).

**Unity 3D Client:**

https://github.com/guywald/serverless-auth-msg-board-unity3d-client

**AWS Serverless backend (using [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/)):**

https://github.com/guywald/serverless-auth-msg-board

Comment: thank you for sharing @Guy! I'm in the process of choosing a cloud provider for my Unity3d game and came across your post when thinking of using API Gateway for a serverless backend. How's it going so far? Are you doing OK with calling API Gateway calls and using AWS overall for the backend of your game??? would LOVE to know!

Comment: And what about serverless? Never heard of it till I saw your post. It looks amazing. How's that going with your Unity3d integration? Why not use API Gateway?

Comment: Serverless Framework gives you the ability to create AWS Api Gateway endpoints and have them invoke lambda functions. With this framework it's easier to define and deploy this. There are other tools like SAM (Serverless Appication Model). These tools put the definition of the Api Gateway endpoint (the url for the REST) and the lambda being invoked at the same place in the JSON/YAML which defines your REST Api.
On the other hand, you don't need a REST Api with Api Gateway to access AWS services, this can be done with the AWS SDK directly.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforunity/developerguide/what-is-unity-plugin.html

Comment: thanks for sharing @Guy. Have you tried the Visual Studio serverless.template ? IT seems to fill the same role as serverless but is made by AWS directly?

Comment: Hi @GuyWald, I've attempted to implement your solution above however am getting a 403 error on the API gateway, message in the logs is as follows: -- "Authorization header must begin with the algorithm name, which cannot include an equal-sign: 'X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=<REST SNIPPED FOR BREVITY>... Any thoughts on what might be wrong? I've implemented you code exactly...

Comment: Hi @ElasticThoughts, maybe its the lambda / api gateway configuration. What do you think about the following response from AWS forums? 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=693557#693557